# Is there any advantage to define function name in "var new_function = function name(){};" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was running a program to change some parts of my javascript code when it bugged in the declaration of a var as a function like this:

```
var some_function = function name(args){
//do stuff
};
```

The code itself works, but I was just wondering if it's ok to remove the "name" for all functions that i find like this (for it doesn't break it in the other problem that analyzes my javascript) or if it could be any use for it that I can't see.

removing the "name":

```
var new_function = function(){/*do stuff*/};
```

Note: the original file where it first happen  it was in [jquery-1.6.4.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js) in:

```
jQuerySub.fn.init = function init( selector, context ) {
    if ( context && context instanceof jQuery && !(context instanceof jQuerySub) ) {
        context = jQuerySub( context );
    }

    return jQuery.fn.init.call( this, selector, context, rootjQuerySub );
};
```

ty for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `name` identifier of Function Expressions, is accessible only within the function itself.

In your jQuery example the `init` identifier isn't even used, so I think the only advantage to name the function it's just for debugging purposes, a debugger will be able to show you the function name in a long stack of calls.

Compare:

[image: anonymous functions on stack]

Vs.

[image: named functions on stack]

Disadvantages exist, a long-standing bug on IE <=8 makes named function expressions to leak the name identifier to its enclosing scope, moreover, creating two function objects, for example:

```
var foo = function bar() {}; 

typeof bar; // "function" on IE
foo === bar; // false, two different objects
```

To avoid the side effects of this bug there are several workarounds, for example, to work inside an immediately called function, to create a function declaration within that scope, and return it, e.g.:

```
jQuerySub.fn.init = (function () {
  function init( selector, context ) {
    //...
  }

  return init;
})();
```

And other similar ways, I would recommend you to check the following article:

- [Named Function Demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Comment: A disadvantage is that named function expressions will create two functions in IE afaik (or something like that).

Comment: @FelixKling, added a note about NFE's.

Comment: Ty for your answer. I've just also tryed in firefox 7.0.1 and it recognizes the name inside the function but not out of if.